# How to retrieve device token from Parse Installation

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, migrate, pushwoosh, devicetoken

I have built a Trigger.io application and have been using parse for my push notifications.

I am now migrating to pushwoosh for my push notification needs, however I realise that parse uses Installation id for pushing notifications but pushwoosh uses device token.

I was unable to retrieve the device token from parse as the available function only allows me to retrieve the installtion id.

```
forge.parse.installationInfo(function (info) {
    //info object only stores the installation id
    forge.logging.info("installation: "+JSON.stringify(info));
});
```

However for pushwoosh, I require the device id from the server end to push a message to a specific device

```
//Notify some devices or a device:
Pushwoosh.notify_devices(message, devices, other_options)
```

So my question is after I migrate my the data from parse over to pushwoosh, how do I retrieve all the device token for all my old users so that I can send notification messages to the users who were using parse for notifications as well?

Answer (score 2):

For Android you can get the `devicetoken` using the code below. `Trigger.io` does not have a `JavaScript` wrapper for the same in their API. You can build it though for your purpose.

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Zhen Does it help?